# Is there any plugin for Intellij (Android Studio) where Entity Code is formatted as Properties and Getters and Setters separately?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, entity, getter-setter, code-formatting

Is there any plugin for Intellij (Android Studio) where Entity Code is formatted as Properties and Getters and Setters separately?

> Input:

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String department;
    // Getters and Setters
    private String employeeId;
    // Getters and setters
}
```

> Output:

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private String employeeId;
    // Getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shift+Ctrl+Alt+L` while in the Editor brings up the **Reformat File** dialog. There, you can choose to 'Rearrange code'. It should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: No problem. If you care to give my rep a boost, mark it as best answer.